# Upload json files through Amazon API gateway, S3, SQS and Lambda

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-api-gateway

I have my APP running on EC2 instance that accept in input a json file and return an elaborated json file as output.
I need to manage many answer to the server, so I'm trying to configure AWS services.
My idea is to create an API Gateway that receive
json file input, write on S3, than SQS read the notification of put and pass the request to the EC2 server, maybe trough a Lambda function.
Than the server write the json elaborated to another S3 bucket and SNS send notification to the client.

Is this a correct way to use AWS services or there is another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like very complicated workflow for no good reason. What's the point exactly of using so many services just to for your ec2 instance get that json? You can have direct endpoint to your ec2 instance. If you want API gateway as a wrapper on your endpoints, you can have that too. But just send that json directly to ec2 or api gateway to ec2 instead of api gateway -> s3 -> sqs -> lambda -> ec2.

Comment: i could have many requests at the same time to the server so i was thinking to manage with Sqs, is it wrong?

Comment: If you are using SQS to autoscale you EC2 instances, you still should use simple user request -> public ec2 server -> sqs -> your processing ec2 servers. Using api gateway, s3, sqs and lambda just to get that json in your processing server seems complicated and I don't see what it gives exactly.

Comment: the focus is to use "only" aws services because they are fully managed

Comment: Ec2 is aws service. Users making direct request to your ec2 instance is still using only aws services.

Comment: Ok comments really useful, but if i want to store the incoming and outgoing json on a s3 bucket how can i do?

Comment: This Answer does not answer OP original Question